# No Certificate Templates in Certification Authority

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority

I have installed AD Certificate Services on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard edition. But when I open Certification Authority snap-in, there is no Certificate Templates folder:

[image]

Why? Have I missed something when installed it?

Comment: Have you installed it as a standalone CA, or as Enterprise? I think you need Enterprise for the Templates to work.

Comment: Very interested as I will need to update/replace my PKI one day... Posts I've read sounds like they tried to make PKI the same on all editions of 2012. Do you have the ADCS Management Tools installed? Powershell:  Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-ADCS-Mgmt

Comment: I very much guess MichelZ is right! Well, certificate templates are published in forest root. It could somehow be, that you do not have read access there. Could you please check and answer this?

Answer (score 5):

In 2012 it comes as a separate mmc Snap-In (Certificate Templates)

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify "LoadDefaultTemplates = 1" in your CAPolicy.inf file before installing and setting up the CA role? If not, you'll need to manually define your published templates using the Certificate Templates snap-in tool.

Recommend you review the [CAPolicy.inf synatax article on TechNet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/10/15/windows-server-2008-r2-capolicy-inf-syntax/)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have a standalone CA installed. Try to install Enterprise CA.